# Подключение jQuery плагинов ASP.NET

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Прописываю в BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryconf").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-confirm.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
          "~/Content/site.css",
          "~/Content/jquery-confirm.min.css"));
```

Как я понял, jQuery и основные стили, которые вызываются в `_Layout`, работают на всех страницах. Так что на странице, где я хочу использовать `jquery-confirm`, я пишу только это:

```
@Scripts.Render("jqueryconf")

@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "About", "Home", new { @class = "btn btn-danger", id = "btn-delete"})  

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/del.js"></script>
```

В файле `del.js` пишу:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn-delete").click(function () {
        $.alert({
            title: '123',
            context: 'hello',
        });
    });
});
```

Вот такие ошибки:

[image: Ошибки]

Сам jQuery работает, а вот [jquery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) - нет. Не могу понять, что я делаю не так.

Comment: А без бандла работало? Если просто скрипт в Layout подключить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключалось в том, что я подключал `jQuery` два раза, первый раз в `_Layout`, другой на странице.